# ACRA formkey where to get it?

Tags: android, acra

So I tried to follow instructions of https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/BasicSetup but its too old or something.
 
Using my own gmail account I did import the csv file but there is no option "Create a **LEGACY** Form" in tools menu but only "Create form". If I create a form there are no fields of imported csv file (like I can see on screenshot in BasicSetup document) but it prompts to add fields manually using "Add item". And there is no any formkey around. The http link of form is looks like: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1KNF_R4_Re0X0giFfEXwqXY50mpnFvQUvp0NLkKxyI/edit# or if I choose "view live form" it is https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1KNF_R4_Re0X0giFfEXwqXY50mpnFvQUvp0NLkKxyI/viewform
 As you can see there is no formkey included.
 
So the question is there I can find that fomkey now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google spreadsheets are not supported on [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/Notice-on-Google-Form-Spreadsheet-usage). Use a [third party provider](http://www.bugsense.com/docs/android#acra) like BugSense instead or write your own error collector.

Comment: They should remove the section of google-docs used setup in https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/BasicSetup if there is no support for this feature anymore.

Comment: @Stan I agree. I clicked on the edit button and it seems to allow me to edit the page. Perhaps it is a public wiki ?

Comment: I updated the ACRA wiki recently, I'm sorry that the situation has been quite unclear for a few months since Google asked me to stop supporting GoogleDocs Forms for automatic reports submission.

Answer (score 5):

As the use of `Google Docs` is deprecated for `ACRA` I recommend you to use `BugSense` as your Back-End service:

**1.** Go to their site and sign in: http://www.bugsense.com/

**2.** Create a new project to monitor in `BugSense` site, as a result you will receive an `API Key` for this application.

**3.** Finally add this line to you Application class in you project:

```
@ReportsCrashes(formUri = "http://www.bugsense.com/api/acra?api_key=YOUR_API_KEY", formKey="")
```

You can also check this blog post I wrote on:

[Crash Reports and Usage Monitoring](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=630)

Comment: formKey is not available in 4.6.0

Answer (score 0):

I have tried ACRA with my custom domain which handled by google   and  at that time i could not found any option to create  to

> Create a LEGACY Form

then after i have tried with my personal gmail account and its works .

so i came to conclusion is that :

> ACRA dose not support Third party domain even-though they provided
>   google .

Comment: I was trying this from my gmail account so there are no 3rd party services ot smth involved.