# What is formkey and how to get formkey?

Tags: android, facebook-chat, acra

I am developing xmpp chat for facebook sample demo application..My ApplicationActivity extends Application.For that one i follow this url https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/BasicSetup.In this tutorial i saw @ReportsCrashes(formKey="", logcatArguments={},formUri="",....etc) what is that formkey,logcatArguments,formUri...etc how I can get formkey and logcatArguments and formUri and where i get...

I don't know about ReportsCrashes and org.acra I am new at this.

Any one Please help me..Thanks in feature..

Answer (score 1):

This depends on where you want to send the reports to. When you are using Google Docs ([might be deprecated now](https://plus.google.com/118444843928759726538/posts/GTTgsrEQdN6)), you have to use your formKey you got from your google docs document. If you want to store the reports on your own server, you can leave the formKey field blank. The only thing you have to do is to enter a valid url to your server (formUri = ....).

The other strings are for the type of dialog, which should or which shouldn't appear. Have a look at the [advanced usage](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/AdvancedUsage). There are some useful examples for notifications in the statusbar, alert-dialogs or toasts.

e.g. toast notifications:

```
@ReportsCrashes(formUri = "http://www.backendofyourchoice.com/reportpath",
            mode = ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST,
            forceCloseDialogAfterToast = false, // optional, default false
            resToastText = R.string.crash_toast_text)
```

Instead of using your own server, you can use BugSense. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15924289/acra-formkey-where-to-get-it?rq=1) thread on stackoverflow.

I copied the important post:

> As the use of `Google Docs` is deprecated for `ACRA` I recommend you to use `BugSense` as your Back-End service:
>
> **1.** Go to their site and sign in: http://www.bugsense.com/
>
> **2.** Create a new project to monitor in `BugSense` site, as a result you will receive an `API Key` for this application.
>
> **3.** Finally add this line to you Application class in you project:
>
> @ReportsCrashes(formUri = "http://www.bugsense.com/api/acra?api_key=YOUR_API_KEY", formKey="")